# Reference anonymous inner class from other class file

Tags: java, java-native-interface, chess

Hi guys is there anyway that I can reference or use this anonymous inner class in other classes?

```
private DgtebdllLib.CallbackFunctionCharPtr getScan = new DgtebdllLib.CallbackFunctionCharPtr()
```

The full code is below and I found this Java code [here](http://www.dgtprojects.com/site/dgtsupport/repair-manuals/doc_details/202-java-dll-example). This is an example for interfacing with DGT chessboard DLL using Java.
What I just like to do is just to get the data str String variable from getScan anonymous inner class. Any help/suggestions is deeply appreciated. Thanks

```
public class DemoDll
{
    private static boolean running = true;
    private static DgtebdllLib dll = null;

    /**
     * Callback implementation function for the received status
     */
    private DgtebdllLib.CallbackFunctionCharPtr getStatus = new DgtebdllLib.CallbackFunctionCharPtr()
    {
        @Override
        public void callback(Pointer data)
        {
            String str = data.getString(0);
            System.out.println("Received status: " + str);
        }
    }; 

    /**
     * Callback implementation function for the evaluation of the received scan
     */
    private DgtebdllLib.CallbackFunctionCharPtr getScan = new DgtebdllLib.CallbackFunctionCharPtr()
    {
        @Override
        public void callback(Pointer data)
        {
            String str = data.getString(0);
            System.out.println("Received a scan: " + str);
        }
    };
```

Comment: If it is declared public static, yes.

Comment: You could provide a getter for the member variable `getScan`...

Comment: Hi Holger thanks for answering. If its a member class why can't create a new instance of it from another class ?

Comment: Hi Arnaud, its declared as private and the way its declared is even not familiar to me. I have used inner classes before in Swing but not in this manner.

Comment: Actually what I just want to do is to get the value of str inside that member class. You see the way I understood the program is that the whole class is  placed in an infinite loop and if there are any changes in the board such as moving a pawn that member class will also be called and str will contain the position of the chess piece in the board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are asking the wrong question. The call back encapsulates an *action* and all you have to do is to implement the desired action. So If you want to store the received data, just store it, e.g. in the outer instance:

```
public class DemoDll {
    private static boolean running = true;
    private static DgtebdllLib dll = null;

    String status;
    String scan;

    /**
     * Callback implementation function for the received status
     */
    private DgtebdllLib.CallbackFunctionCharPtr getStatus
     = new DgtebdllLib.CallbackFunctionCharPtr() {
        @Override
        public void callback(Pointer data) {
            status = data.getString(0);
            System.out.println("Received status: " + status);
        }
    }; 

    /**
     * Callback implementation function for the evaluation of the received scan
     */
    private DgtebdllLib.CallbackFunctionCharPtr getScan
     = new DgtebdllLib.CallbackFunctionCharPtr() {
        @Override
        public void callback(Pointer data) {
            scan = data.getString(0);
            System.out.println("Received a scan: " + scan);
        }
    };

    …
```

Now you can access the most recent `status` and `scan` values received by the call-backs without any special “access anonymous inner classes” feature.

Alternatively you can make the values accessible through a member class which is *not* anonymous:

```
public class DemoDll {
    private static boolean running = true;
    private static DgtebdllLib dll = null;

    static class StringRef implements DgtebdllLib.CallbackFunctionCharPtr() {
        String value;

        @Override
        public void callback(Pointer data) {
            value = data.getString(0);
            System.out.println("Received: " + value);
        }
    }
    StringRef status;
    StringRef scan;

    …
```

so then you can use `status` and `scan` as call-backs and read `status.value` and `scan.value` afterwards.

Comment: hmmmm... why didn't i think of this before. I am going to try this out. I was just confused with how this member class is implemented. I've dealt with Swing inner classes before but this one is very new to me. Thanks Holger

Comment: Thanks very much Holger for your suggestion now am able to proceed with other things

Answer (score 0):

The essence of a class being *anonymous* is that you cannot refer to it by name. Usually, though, it is enough to refer to its *instances* using the static type of its supertype.

There is a thoeretical, roundabout way to reflectively refer to the anonymous class by its binary name, but that would not be recommended.

Comment: Hi Marko, thanks for answering, am not that good with reflections but can I  make a getter or setter for this? as Oli suggested in the comments?